# Add item to array

Tags: php, arrays, paypal, product

How to add another item to this array:

```
$item = array('Quantity' => 1,
              'Product' => array ('Name' => 'name of test product',
                                  'UnitPrice' => array ('Gross' => 10000,
                                                        'Net' => 7800,
                                                        'Tax' => 22,
                                                        'TaxRate' => '22',
                                                        'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN')
                                 )
             );
```

> Array ( [Quantity] => 1 [Product] => Array ( [Name] => name of test
>   product [UnitPrice] => Array ( [Gross] => 10000 [Net] => 7800 [Tax] =>
>   22 [TaxRate] => 22 [CurrencyCode] => PLN ) ) )

Comment: `$item[] = "another item";` or `$item[] = array("another", "item");`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the structure a little to do this:

```
$item = array(  
    0 => array (
        'Name' => 'name of test product',
        'UnitPrice' => array (
            'Gross' => 10000, 'Net' => 7800, 'Tax' => 22, 'TaxRate' => '22',   'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN',
         )
         'Quantity' => 1,
     ),
     1 => array (
         'Name' => 'name of test product 2',
         'UnitPrice' => array (
             'Gross' => 10000, 'Net' => 7800, 'Tax' => 22, 'TaxRate' => '22',   'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN',
          )
          'Quantity' => 3,
     ),
 );
```

Comment: I can't change it structure, becouse I send it to something like PayPal

Answer (score 0):

**Example** :

```
$items = array();
$items[] = array('Quantity' => 1,
              'Product' => array ('Name' => 'name of test product',
                                  'UnitPrice' => array ('Gross' => 10000,
                                                        'Net' => 7800,
                                                        'Tax' => 22,
                                                        'TaxRate' => '22',
                                                        'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN')
                                 )
             );
$items[] = array('Quantity' => 1,
              'Product' => array ('Name' => 'name of test product',
                                  'UnitPrice' => array ('Gross' => 10000,
                                                        'Net' => 7800,
                                                        'Tax' => 22,
                                                        'TaxRate' => '22',
                                                        'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN')
                                 )
             );
$items[] = array('Quantity' => 1,
              'Product' => array ('Name' => 'name of test product',
                                  'UnitPrice' => array ('Gross' => 10000,
                                                        'Net' => 7800,
                                                        'Tax' => 22,
                                                        'TaxRate' => '22',
                                                        'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN')
                                 )
             );
...
```

then you can do:

```
foreach ($items as $item){
    some_function_on_paypal($item); // call your function and execute the $item. 
    // it won't change paypal structure.
}
```